# Uncategorized bluetooth headset in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

There is a headphone which I'm connecting via bluetooth. The app receiver gets notified and at certain point m doing

```
 BluetoothDevice device = some object coresponding to the headset;
 BluetoothClass bluetoothClass = device.getBluetoothClass();
```

After that m trying two things:

```
 bluetoothClass.hasService(BluetoothClass.Service.AUDIO)
```

and

```
 bluetoothClass.getMajorDeviceClass()
 bluetoothClass.getDeviceClass()
```

Even though m able to use the same headset via youtube and phone app for audio purpose, m getting Uncategorized category for this device or (hasService is false).

How to handle this case, any examples or suggestions?

Comment: I have found that what you describe happens when I try to extract params from a headset using bonded LE connections. Once bonded, I get the correct/expected CoD and a properly detected Device type too (eg., dual mode).

Comment: i saw this with LE as well..